# Strategy for Nim-like Games

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

Recently I came across a interesting problem. There are several piles of stones. Two players take turns to pick up only one stone from a random pile. If only one pile remains after a player's move, he wins the game. Here is a example. Suppose there are 3 piles.

```
(1 3 3) -> A picks 1 from the first pile   
(3 3) -> B picks 1 from either pile  
(2 3) -> A picks  
(2 2) -> B picks  
(1 2) -> A picks  
(2)   -> A wins
```

Here is the question. If both players are clever, is there a winning strategy for the first player?

This question sounds like Nim-game problem, but the rules are different. I am new to game theory, so I expect a clean and easy-understood answer.

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: It really depends on the configuration. If a winning strategy is always possible, than also B would have a winning strategy after the first move -> a contradiction.

Comment: @Henry Maybe I haven't made it clear. The question is: given the initial configuration, how to decide whether or not the first player would win the game.

Comment: this link may be helpful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem

Comment: All such games are called impartial games and can be converted to nim using Grundy theorem

Comment: @VikramBhat I am not familiar with SG-function. Can you help me apply it to my problem? Thanks very much.

Comment: Check this link : http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=algorithmGames It is one of the best introductory tutorial of algorithmic game :)